# Every graph of degree 2 is planar

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> A graph is planar if it can be drawn on flat paper so that no lines
>   cross each other.
>
> Suppose G is a component where every node has degree 2, and no node in
>   G has arc to itself. Is G necessarily planar?

I tend to think that every graph is planar but I have no idea how to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Try to think of the circle and the points are on the circle (in the plane)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is enough to prove for components. Every connected graph which is 2-regular is a cycle. Since you are not considering loops, we leave out the cycle on one vertex (but you should note that a cycle on 1 vertex is still planar and the vertex has degree 2). Every cycle is planar. That is to say every 2-regular connected graph is planar.